# Laravel how to move data from table to another using button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

Is there any simple way to move data from table to another table using the id? I want to get all the info inside the first table using the id, insert it to another table, and then delete it from current one using Laravel.

In my Html table. For example I have pending reservation table and there's an action button "accept" then if I will click it the data will go to the accepted reservation table.

Pleaser refer to this photo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xidi.png)

Comment: I want to use button to hold the function for moving the data to another table.

Comment: Do you mean database tables or html tables?

Comment: In my Html table. For example I have pending reservation table and there's an action button "accept" then if I will click it the data will go to the accepted reservation table.

Comment: I already edit my post please refer to the photo. Thanks

Comment: I have answered your question.  If there's something else you want then specify that else close this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [sortablejs](https://sortablejs.github.io/) to do the trick

check this  example from the [docs](https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#shared-lists)

Comment: How can i do that in laravel using a button?

Comment: there is no need to  use any laravel on server feature it's all on client side .
  if u need to do anything with server like change column value in db u can use  events [options](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#options) on `sortablejs`
i think  `onEnd` event will do the trick and make ajax request to change it

Answer (score 0):

if you are using datatable , then you can do something like that

```js
var table1 = $("#pending").DataTable();
var table2 = $("#reserved").DataTable();

$(document).on("click", "#pending .move", function () {
  var row = table1.row( $(this).parents('tr') );
    var rowNode = row.node();
    row.remove();
 
    table2
        .row.add( rowNode )
        .draw();
});


$(document).on("click", "#reserved .move", function () {
  var row =table2.row( $(this).parents('tr') );
    var rowNode = row.node();
    row.remove();
 
    table1
        .row.add( rowNode )
        .draw();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table id="pending" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm move">move</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm move">move</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm move">move</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="reserved" class="table mt-5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
   
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```